# How to filter related field(array) Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)
    passNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    passGet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, null=True)
    passDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey('Positions', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    startDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    userName = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee", null=True, blank=True)
    is_fired = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
```

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, related_name='workers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='worked', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_worked = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    fact_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And have 2 serializers

```
class ScheduleReportsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    moneys = MoneyOperationsScheduleSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        exclude = ['employee_id']


class EmployeeReportsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    position = PositionsSerializer(read_only=True)
    worked = ScheduleReportsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'position', 'worked')
```

And viewSet

```
class EmployeeReportsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = EmployeeReportsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Employee.objects.all().filter(is_fired=False).order_by('position__groupName')
        mindate = self.request.query_params.get('mindate')
        maxdate = self.request.query_params.get('maxdate')
        if mindate and maxdate:
            schedule_qs = Schedule.objects.filter(date__date__range=[mindate, maxdate]).order_by('date')
            NEED HELP HERE
        return queryset
```

I need after request reports/?mindate=2023-04-10&maxdate=2023-04-16
Return all Employees and filter WORKED field by mindate=2023-04-10&maxdate=2023-04-16 and order
Something like that

```
"worked": [
{
                "id": 72,
                "moneys": [],
                "is_worked": true,
                "start_time": null,
                "fact_time": null,
                "end_time": null,
                "date": "2023-04-10"
            },
 {
                "id": 55,
                "moneys": [],
                "is_worked": true,
                "start_time": null,
                "fact_time": null,
                "end_time": null,
                "date": "2023-04-11"
            },
            {
                "id": 59,
                "moneys": [],
                "is_worked": true,
                "start_time": null,
                "fact_time": null,
                "end_time": null,
                "date": "2023-04-12"
            },
            ]
```

I tried using chatgpt, but it always gave me some kind of error. Tried using django-filters